# Python: How to get names of arguments in a list in a lambda?

Tags: python, lambda

```
lambda xxxx: a/b
```

What do I put where there are the x's, and how can I use `*args` and `**kwargs` in a lambda? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. The best solution will be using a function with `*args` and possible `**kwargs`:

```
argsneeded = ['foo', 'bar']
def whatever(**kwargs):
    if not all(x in kwargs for x in argsneeded):
        raise ValueError('required kwarg is missing')
```